# Flutter Web check if currently running Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, flutter-web

I recently converted my flutter mobile project to support flutter-web and I know that I can't access Platform.environment as it is a natively mobile function thus I can't use Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST') to determine whether I am currently running unit tests like in flutter mobile environment. Are there any other alternatives for flutter web to determine whether I am currently running Unit Tests?